# Why does the fill tool only color gray?

Tags: animation

I was filling in the eye  of this ghost character and even though I put the fill setting on the brightest white it couldn't get any color than a gray that was way too dark, and when I tried changing the color to something like neon green it still made no difference and gave me the exact same color. I can't find a single thing even close to answering why its doing this and I'm following along with a tutorial and haven't done anything different than the tutorial. Does anyone know what's going on and how to make the actual color I select show up when I fill? [image]

Answer (score 2):

Check your GPencil Layer, if it has its attribute "use lights" checked. If so uncheck it.

In the rendering properties, change the view transform from "filmic" to "standard" and set the look to "none".

[image]